# Flutter view with two big buttons

Tags: flutter

I wanted to make a view with two big buttons. I saw an example with `Row` and `Expanded` inside, however, `Column` did not work the same way. I tried with `Container` of height `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5`, but the paddings I had made the buttons to overflow.

Something like this

[image: example of layout]

**EDIT:** Complete code

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                      child: OutlineButton(
                        onPressed: () => null,
                        child: Text('Button A'),
                      ))),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () => null,
                    child: Text('Button B'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your Column in Flexible and add in your Column `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

```
Flexible(
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    child: OutlineButton(
                      onPressed: () => null,
                      child: Text('Button A'),
                    ))),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                child: OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () => null,
                  child: Text('Button B'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ])),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the property `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in the Column widget to make all the children be stretched in the cross direction (axis X).

You can see a live example of this working here: https://dartpad.dev/825104f44446432166803c0473ea4437

Comment: fyi code is now broken - I know it's been almost 3 years :) The method 'OutlineButton' isn't defined for the type 'Home'.

Comment: works now and you got my vote!

Answer (score 1):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("1"),
              onPressed: (){},
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("2"),
              onPressed: (){},
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```